# How do you write a cron job to backup a MySQL database?

Tags: php, python, mysql, perl, cron

**UPDATE: I do not know Perl or Python as I have said. Don't give me examples because I don't understand it!**

I have looked at other posts here, but do not see any real answer. I use [Go Daddy](http://godaddy.com/Hosting) and would like to backup my MySQL database every day, and if possible only allow 7 backups in the folder at once.

Folder: `_db_backups`
DB Name: `ccadatabase`

Go Daddy says:

> Your Shared Hosting account supports the following languages and associated interpreter lines:
>
> Perl: #!/usr/bin/perl
>
> Python 2.2: #!/usr/bin/python2.2
>
> Python 2.3: #!/usr/bin/python2.3
>
> Python 2.4: #!/usr/bin/python2.4
>
> Ruby: #!/usr/local/bin/ruby
>
> Bash: #!/bin/bash
>
> The installed versions of PHP 4 and PHP 5 do not support the interpreter specification in a PHP file. In order to run a PHP script via Cron, you must specify the interpreter manually. For example:
>
> PHP 4: /web/cgi-bin/php "$HOME/html/test.php"
>
> PHP 5: /web/cgi-bin/php5 "$HOME/html/test.php5"

Is there anyone who can help me write a quick script to make this process automated? That would be great! I don't know any Perl/Python, so if you could explain your code I would really appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: There are tons of [examples](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/backup-methods.html) out there.

Comment: Have a separate cron line that deletes anything older than 7 days

Comment: @Mel @ysth, I wrote specifically, I do not know python or perl, so I don't know the syntax and cant write a script just by looking at some examples.

Comment: My point is that you don't need to write a script. Many have been made already. You do however need to understand the principles on the page I linked.

Answer (score 2):

here's what I use

```
#!/bin/bash  
DATE_NOW=$(date +%Y%m%d)
BACKUP_DIR=/Users/nico/${DATE_NOW}

mkdir -p ${BACKUP_DIR}

echo "Dumping data ..."
mysqldump -ume -hlocalhost -ppass db > ${BACKUP_DIR}/${DATE_NOW}-mybackup.sql
```

Note: you'll have to change the mysqldump variables with user password db etc

Comment: can you put my data in there? Like the foldername and DB name and put where I should put the user and pass? I don't understand the script you posted, but if you can show me where to put the items I would appreciate it. Like what is ume, hlocalhost, ppass.

Comment: @JD Audi: -u, -h, and -p specify the database user, hostname, and password, respectively.  @Gevious: use another variable for the date-based directory, in cast the date changes between the mkdir and mysqldump

Comment: @ysth so instead of -ume I would put -username?

Comment: no, -uusername to have user 'username' instead of 'me'

Comment: @ysth good point. I seem to remember having trouble with the variables referencing the date in bash, so left it as it is.